# View Compiler Mangled Names in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, name-mangling, visual-c++-2008

How do I view the compiler-generated mangled names for overloaded functions in C++? I'm using VC9 but answers for other compilers are welcome too.

**Edit:** I find all the answers useful here. Accepting the one I liked best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look in the map file. Assuming you have map file generation turned on.

Comment: What if you have multiple overloads of the same function?

Comment: Then you will see many functions with the same name wrapped in different mangled forms, for each overload.

Comment: Well you will then see multiple version of that function with each of there mangled names forms. Thus the purpose of name mangling, to avoid name conflicts.

Answer (score 8):

You can see the decorated function names by using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Open any DLL\EXE in dependency walker and in right pane you can see a list of decorated function names.

Answer (score 7):

Since you also ask about other compilers. There is a tool called nm on the gnu toolchain. You will get it on linux and cygwin, and I believe that it is also available in mingw. Calling it with no parameters will show the mangled symbols in the binary. Calling it with --demangle will do the obvious.

Answer (score 5):

You can view decorated (mangled) names with [Dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

While all the above works, there is a nicely [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw3h504y(VS.80).aspx) way to view the mangled names by use of [Listing Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6(VS.80).aspx):  Project Property Pages -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output.

(EDIT:)

There is a reason only Listing files and [DUMPBIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b06ww5dd(VS.80).aspx) are documented as ways to see decorated names. Both the map file and dependency walker, suggested as solutions, display *only* decorated names. If you have multiple overloads of a function name, you'll have a hard time matching them to the various decorated names you'd see.  (That's more or less reconstructing the decoration scheme. While [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491115/where-is-documentation-on-the-microsoft-visual-studio-c-name-mangling-scheme/841607#841607), it defeats the whole original purpose.)

Answer (score 2):

linux gnu tool chain nm command can be used to see mangled name.

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

int fun1(){}
int fun1(int){}
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

```
#g++ name_decoration_2.cpp
#nm a.out
...
...
000000000040064e T _Z4fun1i
0000000000400648 T _Z4fun1v
U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```