# Calling C++ code from C using inbuilt c++ classes and templates

Tags: c++, extern-c

So I want to use `string class` and `multiset template` of `C++.`

My original code interfaces from `Python` to `C` using `ctypes` and now I am trying to interface `C` to `C++`. (If there is any direct interfacing between `Python` & `C++`, I would welcome the suggestion but scanning through a couple of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, I found this method to be more feasible.
@n.m in comments provided solution to this, but I would still like to know if it is possible to interface C & C++ for educational purpose)

So here is a simple example to reproduce what happens when I try to merge with string class...

```
ex.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cppstr(char *);

void str(char *x) { 
    cppstr(x);                    
}

int main() {
    char *x;
    x = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    str(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my c file.

```
ex.cpp

#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void cppstr(char *s) {
   string x = "HELLO" + "WORLD";
   strcpy(s, x.c_str());
}
```

Above is cpp File.

If I compile using `gcc` or `g++`, it doesn't compile and instead gives linker errors related to string.

```
 compiler ex.c ex.cpp
```

What is a solution for string and multiset both?

Comment: "If there is any direct interfacing between Python & C++" there very much is more than one. Try boost.python or pybind11. It makes no sense to go through C.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. I will look into boost library, But I would still keep the question open to know if this possible.

Comment: Look up "name mangling" or "name decoration". 
[Here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754865/view-compiler-mangled-names-in-c)